# Разложить число на байты, для передачи по smbus

Tags: python

Есть число, например 1234. Мне его необходимо разбить на два байта и передать их на другое устройство.

Я пытаюсь разложить так:

```
number = 1234
bus.write_byte(address, (number >> 8))
bus.write_byte(address, (number & 0xff))
```

Что я делаю не так? Подобный код, но на языке С, работает корректно.

Comment: работает.......

Comment: `number.to_bytes(2, "big")` - преобразовать число в 2 байта, порядок big endian (младшие байты "справа").

Comment: Пытаетесь, а что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С виду всё работает правильно.

```
number = 1234
print(hex(number), hex(number >> 8), hex(number & 0xff))
```

Вывод:

```
0x4d2 0x4 0xd2
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй следующую конструкцию:

```
freq2phase = 4294967295    
freq2phase = freq2phase.to_bytes(4, byteorder="big", signed=False) #на 4 байта разбиваем число!
```

По итогу получишь:

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```